# margin auto not taken into account

Tags: css, margin

I have defined the following CSS class

```
.tiles .tile > a {
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      margin-left: auto !important; 
      margin-right: auto !important;
      max-width: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 1em;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 3; }
```

However, `margin-right: auto` and `margin-left: auto` are not taken into account (with or without `!important`, and so my tag is not centered.
Is it because of the flex?
Do you know what causes the problem?

Thx!

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to TerminalFlow who helped me identify where the problem came from, here is the code that solved it:

```css
.tiles .tile > a {
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
      margin-left: auto !important; 
      margin-right: auto !important;
      max-width: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      padding: 1em;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 3; }
```

This way, the tag is centered and still respects the overlay that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have set the `display: flex` and then set the `position: absolute` [technically doesn't matter](https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-and-absolute-positioning/) but your `top: 0` overrides all the flex properties.

You should be able to center everything with your css being something like this:

```css
.tiles .tile > a {
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
      max-width: 300px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 1em;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom: 0;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      z-index: 3; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Indeed when I follow your example my tag becomes centered, however I loose the overlay that I had set with position: absolute. Would you happen to know how I could bypass that? Would creating a sub class inside work or not likely?

Comment: nevermind, thanks to your pointers I found a way to bypass the problem, I just posted the answer. Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful!